# Problems with a wordpress commutative diagram

Tags: diagrams

I am trying to create a wordpress commutative diagram. The code that I have entered is

> `$latex \usepackage[all]{xy} \xymatrix{F(M)\ar[r]^{F(f)}\ar[d]^{m_M} & F(M')\ar[d]^{m_{M'}}\\G(M)\ar[r]^{G(f)}& G(M')}$`

However, "formula does not parse". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't just use a LaTeX statement inside WordPress. Which Plugins do you have installed?

Comment: There is a Wordpress.SX site as well, you can ask the same question there (or it will be migrated to that place), I'll can answer there too. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

The output/way depends on the plugin used in WordPress

This uses the `QuickLaTeX` plugin -- place this content on a Wordpress post, if QuickLaTeX is installed and correctly setup:

```
[latexpage]

$\xymatrix{F(M)\ar[r]^{F(f)}\ar[d]^{m_M} & F(M')\ar[d]^{m_{M'}}\\G(M)\ar[r]^{G(f)}& G(M')}$
```

[image]

In QuickLateX setup use the settings as shown below

[image]

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: Sorry I seem to be really technologically challenged. Now that I have installed the quicklatex file on my computer (it is a zipped file), what do I do?

Comment: As in, how do I activate it on my blog, if that makes sense?

Comment: @egreg: No, not really ;-)

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: See my update with a screen shot