# Any suggestions on how to use commutative diagrams in Wordpress

Tags: html, commutative-diagrams, latex2html

I started a blog on Wordpress a few months back and I used Luca Trevesian's latex2wp to change my latex documents into html for wordpress.

I am wanting to use a commutative diagram on my blog but it doesn't parse in latex2wp. I have a few hacks none of which will only provide a temporary solution.

1. Use an external QuickLatex which parses the latex code into a PNG and post it with the text. Not ideal if I have many commutative diagrams.

[Problems with a wordpress commutative diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219736/problems-with-a-wordpress-commutative-diagram)

2. An alternative is to use this other software written in Haskell which converts latex into html for wordpress. This changes latex code into images. Preferably I don't want to have PNG files in my wordpress blog. Also, I would have to edit the blogs to make it consistent

http://www.carloangiuli.com/blog/latex2wp/

So I am asking for reference requests to see how other people deal with these problems or if people try to circumvent this on a diagram to diagram basis by putting an appropriate png file. But I would presume those doing category theory or homology cannot really avoid the problem which is why I am curious to hear your solutions.